# Insert or Update Condition in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have two table (tb_account & tb_reg) and they have a relation based on    `user_id`   .    `user_id`    on    `tb_account`    already exist when user make account registration.

I'm trying to insert or update a table in the database but it depends if the row not exist, then it will    `insert`    new row. if not, it will    `update`    the row.

first, user have to fill in several forms into    `tb_reg`    based on    `user_id`    and its success.
But when he want to update the forms for the second time, the condition isn't working.
I've got an error like this    `Duplicate entry '23' for key 'user_id'`   .

here is my model:

```
<pre>
$pen = [
            'tpt_lahir' => $post['tpt_lahir'],
            'tgl_lahir' => $post['tgl_lahir'],
            'agama' => $post['agama']
        ];

    $user_id=$this->session->userdata('userid');
    //user_id in this session is from tb_account
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_reg WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($query != $user_id) {
        $this->db->set('user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->insert('tb_reg', $pen); 
    } else {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->update('tb_reg', $pen);
    }
</pre>
```

Surely, the problems is from the condition (`if else`) but i can't fixed it. Anyone?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You forgot to call  **num_rows()** function your code should be this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_reg WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if($query->num_rows() == '0' ) {
    $this->db->set('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->insert('tb_reg', $pen); 
} else {
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->update('tb_reg', $pen);
}
```

> Hope this helps